# Datastax Opscenter issue: dashboard timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I installed Datastax community version in an EC2 server and it worked fine. After that I tried to add one more server and I see two nodes in the Nodes menu but in the main dashboard I see the following error:

```
Error: Call to /Test_Cluster__No_AMI_Parameters/rc/dashboard_presets/ timed out.
```

One potential rootcause I can see is the name of the cluster? I specified something else in the cassandra.yaml but it looks like opscenter is still using the original name? Any help would be grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because cluster name change wasn't made properly. I found it easier to change the cluster name before starting Cassandra cluster. On top of this, only one instance of opscentered needs to run in one single cluster. datastax-agent needs to be running in all nodes in the cluster but they need to point to the same opscenterd (change needs to be made at /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml)